# Deadlock when synchronizing two simple python3 scripts using 0mq (ZeroMQ)

Tags: python, synchronization, deadlock, zeromq, low-latency

I get this strange deadlock when I try to synchronize two python3 scripts using 0mq (**`ZeroMQ`**). The scripts run fine for several thousand iterations, but sooner or later they both stop and wait for each other. I am running both scripts from different CMD-Windows on Windows 7.

I cannot figure out
 **why such a deadlock is even possible**.
 **What can go wrong here?**

**Script A:**

```
while (1):
   context = zmq.Context()
   socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
   socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:10001')
   msg = socket.recv()                        # Waiting for script B to send done
   # ............................................................................
   # ... do something useful (takes only a few millisecs)
   # ............................................................................     
   context = zmq.Context()
   socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
   socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:10002')
   socket.send_string("done")                 # Tell script B we are done
```

**Script B**

```
while (1):
   # ............................................................................
   # ... do something useful (takes only a few millisecs)
   # ............................................................................
   context = zmq.Context()
   socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
   socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:10001')
   socket.send_string("done")               # Tell script A we are done

   context = zmq.Context()
   socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
   socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:10002')
   msg = socket.recv()                      # Waiting for script A to send done
```

Comment: You are opening new connections all the time and never closing one. You are probably hitting the max limit of connections in your OS

Comment: I tried a quick hack just to verify this. I will improve the code later, but for now I just put a "socket.close()" after each "send_string()" and "recv()". This should at least make sure that only 2 connections are open at a time. Now it crashes even faster. Does this tell me that hitting max connections is not the problem or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: Well, you might have noticed, that just a **`.close()`** does not save you. Both of your **`while (1):`** loops spawn as a minimum a pair ( a quad together (!!!) ) of new additional I/O-threads from un-terminated **`.Context( 1 )`**-s into your O/S schedule **on each loop** (!!!). This **will kill sooner or later** any kind of a contemporary O/S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is not a DeadLock case

The code, sure, still needs some care.

Disambiguation: your scenario does not hit into a resources mutual locking state, aka a *DeadLock*. Yes, sure, your code crashes, but most probably not due to a `REQ/REP` DeadLock ( where it might and does appear on a lossy network `tcp:` transport-class ). The posted code is crashing due to **unmanaged resource handling**, not due to reaching a mutual-blocking state of a DeadLock / LiveLock.

---

### How to fix it?

First, let's assume your ultra-low latency-motivated system does not allow to repetitively instantiate anything. There are exceptions to this, but let's be profi.

1. **move** your `.Context()` resource setup ( or inheritance from an outer call ) out of the loop
2. **review**, whether you need and your latency constraints allow you to setup / tear-down a `.socket()` resource twice in each loop-run.
3. **decide**, whether you can live with real `REQ/REP` deadlock once a first message gets lost in the transport-path
4. **enforce** graceful resources-use termination ( `.socket()`-s, O/S `port#`s, `.Context()`-s ). Do not let them hanging unterminated forever, while creating infinite amount of others instead, that devastates any "fault-resilient" system. Resources are never infinite.
5. **design** both signalling and transmission behaviours in a non-blocking manner. This allows you to detect and handle remote-process timeouts and introduce a chance for local remedy / responsive actions.
6. **redesign** the code to a level of secure code you need ( the below example works a few years in a soft-realtime controlled endless loop 24/7/365 in a distributed processing framework with a remote keyboard and some other local- and remote-diagnostic tools ).

---

### What is missing for production-grade code?

Your code has to "envisage" what might have gone wrong, in any part of your distributed system. Yes, it is hard, but necessary. Your remote node -- a communicating counterparty -- stopped responding, lost a message, went rebooted, stalled due to O/S crash, whatever imaginable ( plus a few rather nasty surprised you will find only on-the-fly ... ). This is another Pandora's Box to cover in this small post, which does not mean it is not necessary. It is your life-saving vest.

Design in a non-blocking manner wherever you can, this way you remain in control of events ...

Anyways, **always** release system resources and `.term()` all ZeroMQ `.Context()` instances in a graceful manner -- "tidy up" is a fair practice -- both in real life and the more in the code-empires.

```
# /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
#NONSTOP RESPONDER RAW EXAMPLE:
def aMiniRESPONDER( aTarget2Bind2_URL             = "tcp://A.B.C.D:8889",
                    anExternalPREDICTOR           = None,
                    anExternallyManagedZmqCONTEXT = None,
                    aSpreadMinSafetyMUL           = 3.0,
                    aSilentMODE                   = True
                    ):
   try: # RESOURCES LAYER
        # ... SETUP
        # ------------------------------------------------- .Context()
        # can setup a locally-managed context or re-use
        # anExternallyManagedZmqCONTEXT obtained upon a func Call
        aZmqCONTEXT   = anExternallyManagedZmqCONTEXT or zmq.Context( 1 )   

        # localhost:8887 [REP] ... remote [REQ] peer  .connect() + .send()
        aCtrlPORT_URL = "tcp://*:8887"                                      

        # localhost:8890 [PUB] ... remote [SUB] peers .connect() +
        # .subscribe + .recv( zmq.NOBLOCK ) ( MQL4 cannot .poll() so far ...)
        aSIGsPORT_URL = "tcp://*:8890"                                      
        aXmitPORT_URL = aTarget2Bind2_URL

        aListOfSOCKETs = []

        pass # -------------------------------------------------------------# ZMQ
        try: # -------------------------------------------------------------#
            # try: XmitPORT
            aXmitSOCKET = aZmqCONTEXT.socket( zmq.PAIR )

            # XmitPORT
            aXmitSOCKET.bind(      aXmitPORT_URL )                          
            aListOfSOCKETs.append( aXmitSOCKET )
        except:                                                             
            #    EXC: XmitPORT on Failure: GRACEFUL CLEARING XmitPORT

            msg =  "\nEXC. ZmqError({0:s}) on aXmitSOCKET setup / .bind( {1:s} )"
            print msg.format( repr( zmq.ZMQError() ), aTarget2Bind2_URL )
            raise ValueError( "ZMQ_EXC_EXIT @ XmitPORT SETUP" )
        pass # -------------------------------------------------------------# ZMQ
        try: # -------------------------------------------------------------#
            # try: CtrlPORT    
            # CtrlSOCKET [REP] .recv()s<--[REQ] + .send()s--> [REQ]
            aCtrlSOCKET = aZmqCONTEXT.socket( zmq.REP )                     

            # CtrlPORT <-REQ/REP means a remote peer [REQ] has to
            # .send()+.recv() before sending another CtrlCMD
            aCtrlSOCKET.bind(      aCtrlPORT_URL )                          
            aListOfSOCKETs.append( aCtrlSOCKET )
        except:                                                             
            # EXC: CtrlPORT on Failure: GRACEFUL CLEARING both CtrlPORT
            # and XmitPORT
            msg =  "\nEXC. ZmqError({0:s}) on aCtrlSOCKET setup / .bind( {1:s} )"
            print msg.format( repr( zmq.ZMQError() ), aCtrlPORT_URL )
            raise ValueError( "ZMQ_EXC_EXIT @ CtrlPORT SETUP" )
        pass # -------------------------------------------------------------# ZMQ
        try: # -------------------------------------------------------------#
            # try: SIGsPORT

            # SIGsPORT [PUB] .send()s--> [SUB]s
            aSIGsSOCKET= aZmqCONTEXT.socket( zmq.PUB  )                     

            # SIGsPORT -->  PUB/SUB means a remote peer(s) [SUB] .subscribe() + .recv()
            aSIGsSOCKET.bind(      aSIGsPORT_URL )                          
            aListOfSOCKETs.append( aSIGsSOCKET )
        except:                                                             
            # EXC: SIGsPORT on Failure: GRACEFUL CLEARING both CtrlPORT
            # and XmitPORT and SIGsPORT
            msg =  "\nEXC. ZmqError({0:s}) on aSIGsSOCKET setup / .bind( {1:s} )"
            print msg.format( repr( zmq.ZMQError() ), aSIGsPORT_URL )
            raise ValueError( "ZMQ_EXC_EXIT @ SIGsPORT SETUP" )
        pass # -------------------------------------------------------------# ZMQ

        # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        # ... SETUP YOUR APPLICATION CODE

        try:     # APP LAYER ___________________________________________
           #           what you want to do
           #           here you go ...

        except:  # APP LAYER ___________________________________________
           #           handle EXCs

        finally: # APP LAYER ___________________________________________
           #           your own application post-mortem / pre-exit code

        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   except:  # RESOURCES LAYER .............................................
        # ... code shall handle it's own exceptions + externally caused events

   finally: # RESOURCES LAYER .............................................
        # ... always, ALWAYS gracefully exit ( avoid leakages and dirty things )

        [ allSOCKETs.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 ) for allSOCKETs in aListOfSOCKETs ]
        [ allSOCKETs.close( )                    for allSOCKETs in aListOfSOCKETs ]

        # --------------------------------------------------------------#
        # RESOURCES dismantled, may .term()

        # .TERM(), NOP otherwise
        if not ( aZmqCONTEXT is anExternallyManagedZmqCONTEXT ):        #
                 aZmqCONTEXT.term()                                     #
        return
```

Comment: Oh! The clarification that it isn't a deadlock like I assumed already helps a lot. I will try to improve my code today, based on your suggestions. Should take a closer look on the way 0MQ is supposed to be implemented.

Comment: Completely agree with all 6 recommendations. Each one counts (and takes some time to understand and implement properly). The code example is hard to grasp - wide (comments) and long (many lines of code). Top level communication schema would help. Not sure about `zmq.PAIR` - spec claims, it is considered experimental and that there is no support for reconnection, I was avoiding it, may be I shall reconsider it again with next project.

Answer (score 1):

You shall handle `context` and `socket` creation only once, not with each iteration.

Also, you shall reuse the context (unless you are going to use it from another
thread in your code).

```
try:
    context = zmq.Context()
    rep_sck = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    rep_sck.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:10001')
    rq_sck = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    rq_sck.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:10002')
    while (1):
        msg = rep_sck.recv() # Waiting for script B to send done

        do something useful (takes only a few millisecs)

        rq_sck.send_string("done") # Tell script B we are done
finally:
    rep_sck.close()
    rq_sck.close()
```

The same applies to the 2nd script.

```
try:
    context = zmq.Context()
    rq_sck = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    rq_sck.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:10001')

    rep_sck = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    rep_sck.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:10002')

    while (1):
        do something useful (takes only a few millisecs)

        rq_sck.send_string("done") # Tell script A we are done

        msg = rep_sck.recv() # Waiting for script A to send done
finally:
    rq_sck.close()
    rep_sck.close()
```

**EDIT: Updated code to call `Socket.close()`**

Since pyzmq version 14.3.0 the `Socket.close()` and `Context.term()` are not called automatically
during garbage collection, proper closing of sockets was added.