# How to post from MetaTrader Terminal 5 MQL 5 a request to my nodejs server, which is running locally on my MT5 host?

Tags: node.js, mql4, metatrader4, mql5

I'm trying to get FX rates in my nodejs server and socke.io emit them to the client, while running MetaTrader Terminal 5 or 4.

So I guess I have to use MQL4/5. I know how the handle the request in my nodejs server. What I dont know is where to write the MQL4 code, what to config in my MetaTrader Terminal.

Lets say I want to send EUR/USD bid rate to my nodejs server everytime it gets changed. How do I achieve that, using MT4/5 and MQL4/5?

My nodejs code:

```
app.post('/fxroute', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req);
   let fxRates = req.body // dont know if the payload will be in body
   socket.emit('fxRates', fxRates);
});
```

MQL5 script:

```
#property copyright "Copyright 2017, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart(){
     string  headers;
     char    data[],
             result[];
     string             str = "data=value";        // POST-data, variables to send    
     StringToCharArray( str,                data );
     string          b = CharArrayToString( data );
     Print( "Test:", b ); // just a test of data, if good ... OK, data was setup correctly.

     WebRequest( "POST",
                 "http://localhost:3000/fxroute",
                 NULL,
                 NULL,
                 3000,
                 data,
                 ArraySize( data ),
                 result,
                 headers
                 );
     Print( CharArrayToString( result ) );   // see the results
                                             // it returns
                                             // "Results:" No posted data.
  }
```

When I compile and run, I see that it was executed in MT Experts tab, but on my nodejs server, console logs nothing.

Comment: Fine, **A:** what value do you receive in **`aHttpRetCODE`** from the **`WebRequest()`**-call? **B:** Is the URL permitted ( provide a setup PrintScreen )? **C:** Also may use a trivial python based HTTP-Server ( as was posted in another answer ) so as to validate the `WebRequest()`-POST working and decide where the HTTP-POST-request processing fails to get completed / finished.

Comment: The full source-code for the mock-up **[ `HttpSERVER` ]** is in my post >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/39966404/3666197 You are welcome to enjoy re-using it **for your own debugging + problem isolation purposes ( it's just about a 5 SLOC-s !!! no reason not to do that, is it? )**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Plan of work:

1. **Enable** MT4/5 to use **`{http:|https:}`** transport-class to selected targets
2. **Create** MT4/5 code to execute some kind of `{http:|https:}` based service
3. **Implement** end-to-end logic to be wrapped + hidden inside the dumb http-protocol exchanges

---

### 1) Terminal permissions:

Using Terminal->Tools->Options **enable <kbd>[x]</kbd>** "**Allow a WebRequest URL**" to use a `localhost` `{http:|https:}` URL of your choice, matching the nodejs-server setup, in the list
[image]

### 2) **`WebRequest()`** code inside event-loop

Given your intentions, create an **`MQL4`** script, using either a built-in IDE <kbd>**F4**</kbd> or using an external editor of your choice and save the produced **`.mq4`** script file in **`~an_MT4_Terminal_Home_Directory/MQL4/Scripts`** directory

The event-loop is principally your design job:

```
int start() {
    while !isStopped() {                            // ACK LOOP
           if ( RefreshRates() ) {                  // NEW QUOTE has arrived
                ...                                 // JOB PROCESS Bid
                int aHttpRetCODE = WebRequest(...); // SIG-> NodeJS Server
                ...                                 // JOB PROCESS Response ( if a bi-directional service )
           }
           else {
                Sleep(...);                         // NOP on NACK, Terminal has nothing to do
           }
    }
}
```

[**For further details**, may like to check my other posts on **`WebRequest()`** use-cases and warnings about it's principal limitations.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20WebRequest)

### 3) end-to-end logic

Here comes the creme-ala-creme of your design.

---

### Is there any other way?

Yes, there is. [That would be **the one of my choice** - using **`ZeroMQ`** or **`nanomsg`** on both sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078423/asynchronous-web-requests-for-metatrader/27215797#27215797) ( MT4/5 Terminal & NodeJS ), thus being able to fully [enjoy the freedom of a **full-scale distributed systems design** <sub>( check the principal **`aMiniRESPONDER()`**-prototype example structure for `[SIG,MSG]` jobs in fully distributed systems )</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394023/3666197) .

Comment: basically in my case I will just need 8 FX rate pairs to be send to my nodejs from mt4/5 every time they change i guess the WebRequest method will be ok.

Comment: 2nd block - it looks it is written at Python not MQL. while(!IsStopped()){ if(RefreshRates()){...}else{...}} is in MQL