# How to use MQL with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mql, google-cloud-metrics

I have created a Monitoring Metrics Dashboard in my Google Cloud Console. The dashboard is working as expected, but since my app is highly dependent on those metrics, I was thinking about creating a schedule to see these metrics data and update the server accordingly.

After investigating the dashboards, I have noticed that there is an MQL query. Is there any way to execute this query in my node.js function so I can fetch the data and update the server?

Comment: What research have you done yourself already?

Answer (score 0):

You can try MetaApi https://metaapi.cloud cloud service which provides REST API and WebSocket API access to both MetaTrader 4 and MetaTrader 5 accounts.

Official REST API documentation: https://metaapi.cloud/docs/client

SDKs: https://metaapi.cloud/sdks (javascript, python and Java SDKs are provided as per April 2021)

It supports reading account information, positions, orders, trade history, receiving quotes, and accessing market data.

The service also provides copy trading API https://metaapi.cloud/docs/copyfactory and API to calculate forex trading metrics on a MetaTrader account https://metaapi.cloud/docs/metastats.

Comment: I'm happy that there are community members who mention our service on stackoverflow. However I think the question author actually meant mysql so that this response is not relevant here.

Answer (score -1):

There is a case similar to yours in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42110428/15745106) (answered by user3666197).

And also you can easily connect your nodejs server in mysql. MySQL is one of the most popular open-source databases in the world and efficient as well.

Please follow [Nodejs mysql tutorial](https://codeforgeek.com/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/) for more details about the steps/process process of how to connect nodejs server to mysql.